# Would the Shield Wall feat grant a shield bonus for each adjacent ally, or just one adjacent ally?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, feats, shield

**Situation:** I am believing the feat limits the benefit to only one adjacent ally, but friends state that it should include an additional adjacent ally due to the wording:

> **Benefit:** When *you and an* adjacent ally are each using a shield, your shield bonus to Armor Class increases by 2.

**Question:** Would Shield Wall grant a +2 shield bonus for each adjacent ally (for example, one on my left side, and one on my right side), or does it simply give a +2 shield bonus for having an adjacent ally regardless of how many there are adjacent to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation, no matter the number of allies, you only get +2 to your Shield bonus to AC.

---

> **Benefit**: When *you and an* adjacent ally are each using a shield, your shield bonus to Armor Class increases by 2.

I read *an* here as *at least one*. Nothing in the feat explicitly calls out that it might scale.

---

Feats that have scaling bonuses generally have a much more specific wording. For example looking at (first find on Internet) [Teamwork Benefits](http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/teamwork-benefits):

> Flanking Enhancement
>
> Your team coordinates its attacks with great precision when surrounding a foe, gaining benefits beyond those of standard flanking maneuvers.
>
> **Benefit**: Your benefits increase based on the number of "flanking pairs" attack the same foe. If you have 2 pairs of flankers on a single foe, all 3 of you gain the +4 to hit instead of the standard +2. If you have 3 or more flankers the bonus increases to +6.

Another example, from the War Master's Charge maneuver (Tome of Battle):

> As part of this maneuver, you charge an opponent. [...] For each ally who charges, counting yourself, your charge attack and those of your allies are made with a cumulative +2 bonus (in addition to the normal bonus provided by charging). [...]

This *for each* is fairly typical in my experience.

---

Out of RAW or RAI, I would imagine that the bonus could scale pretty high, with finely packed creatures... at the same time though, Shield Bonuses to AC do not count against Touch AC by default and do not protect against magical attack, and a dense pack of creatures is a juicy target for an area attack.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, it’s irrelevant. The feat doesn’t say it stacks with itself, so even if you get +2 from each adjacent enshielded ally, you would have a bunch of untyped +2 bonuses from the same source (the feat), and they would not stack, but rather overlap. Whether you have one +2 bonus, or a bunch of unstacking +2 bonuses, makes no difference at any point in the game.

If it *did* say they stacked, that itself would make it clear that you get the bonus from each adjacent enshielded ally.